# taylor series without dissipation

Tags: taylor-expansion

I need help.
Determine the Taylor series about the point $(0,-1, 1)$ of
$f(x, y, z) = z^3 - 3z^2 + x^2 + 4yx + 2y + 2z + 16$.

Note. You must not derive.

Thx

Comment: Must not derive? You mean no differentiation?

Comment: **yes, no differentiation**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe what you have to do is rewrite the equation in terms of $x,y+1,z-1$. Then what you are getting is the taylor expansion around $(0,-1,1)$

Comment: **Yes, I know, but how**

Comment: @JameelKomaira write $y=(y+1)-1$ and $z=(z-1)+1$, **keep the parentheses** and expand.